# Pandas Duplicating Data but pivoting columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert this DF

| Location | Date | F1_ID | F1_Name | F1_Height | F1_Status | F2_ID | F2_Name | F2_Height | F2_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 12/31/19 | 1 | Jon | 67 | W | 2 | Anthony | 68 | L |

To this DF by duplicating the rows but switching the data around.

| Location | Date | F1_ID | F1_Name | F1_Height | F1_Status | F2_ID | F2_Name | F2_Height | F2_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 12/31/19 | 1 | Jon | 67 | W | 2 | Anthony | 68 | L |
| USA | 12/31/19 | 2 | Anthony | 68 | L | 1 | Jon | 67 | W |

How can I acheive this in Pandas. I tried creating a copy of the df and renaming the columns but would get an error because of unique indexing

Comment: How would this function on more than 1 row? If there were 2 rows in your source DF would you want 4 rows, or would you want every possible pair?

Comment: There are roughly 8000 rows. I would want to double the amount of rows. so if there were 2 rows I would want 4. I am expecting around 16000 rows when this is done.

Comment: i messed up putting the table into stackoverflow. I have updated to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try a `concat` and `sort_index`:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Location': {0: 'USA'}, 'Date': {0: '12/31/19'},
     'F1_ID': {0: 1}, 'F1_Name': {0: 'Jon'}, 'F1_Height': {0: 67},
     'F1_Status': {0: 'W'}, 'F2_ID': {0: 2},
     'F2_Name': {0: 'Anthony'}, 'F2_Height': {0: 68},
     'F2_Status': {0: 'L'}})

# Columns Not To Swap
keep_columns = ['Location', 'Date']
# Get F1 and F2 Column Names
f1_columns = list(filter(re.compile(r'F1_').search, df.columns))
f2_columns = list(filter(re.compile(r'F2_').search, df.columns))
# Create Inverse DataFrame
inverse_df = df[[*keep_columns, *f2_columns, *f1_columns]]
# Set Columns so they match df (prevents concat from un-inverting)
inverse_df.columns = df.columns

# Concat and sort index
new_df = pd.concat((df, inverse_df)).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df.to_string())
```

Src:

```
  Location      Date  F1_ID F1_Name  F1_Height F1_Status  F2_ID  F2_Name  F2_Height F2_Status
0      USA  12/31/19      1     Jon         67         W      2  Anthony         68         L
```

Output:

```
  Location      Date  F1_ID  F1_Name  F1_Height F1_Status  F2_ID  F2_Name  F2_Height F2_Status
0      USA  12/31/19      1      Jon         67         W      2  Anthony         68         L
1      USA  12/31/19      2  Anthony         68         L      1      Jon         67         W
```

Comment: I failed to mention there are other columns in the DF that relate to both F1 and F2 see edits to main post.

Comment: Updated to include these new persistent columns.

Comment: works perfect now. I tried this but forgot the * before keep_columns and got a different error thank you.